# How to properly configure k8s nginx ingress base url substitution to handle Angular client side routing (LocationStrategy)?

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-router, kubernetes-ingress

We have Angular based web application hosted on Kubernetes cluster.
Ingress for this application configured to add base URL:

```
{
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "test-app",
    "namespace": "acceptance-testing",
    ...
    "annotations": {    
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url": "true",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": "true"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "path": "/at/test-app",
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "test-app",
                "servicePort": 80
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

When we enter URL including client routing parts into the browser then ingress adds whole this URL as a base which is not correct in our scenario.

For example for *https://server/at/test-app/some-page* request base URL should be *https://server/at/test-app/* but we receiving *https://server/at/test-app/some-page/*

We've switched to Angular hash routing location strategy and now it works properly but we want to know if there is some way to make location routing strategy works with nginx ingress?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: Did you come up with any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some concept:

1. `/at/test-app/some-page/` must route to `/at/test-app`, this will have a Angular App, then Angular will process `/some-page/`
2. Non-Angular path (e.g: .js, .css, etc...) don't rewrite it
3. I don't know why `"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/at/test-app"` is look like not work in my environment (gke 1.11.6-gke.2, ingress: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.22.0)

```
{
    ...
    "annotations": {    
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "nginx",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url": "true",
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet": |   <-- change to this
        rewrite /at/test-app/([^.]+)$ /at/test-app break;      <--   rewrite path if no .
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": "true"
    }
    ....
}
```